# Why does Unity lack many of the string manipulation functions?

Tags: unity

I just learned that Unity lacks the `string.Where` function, the `string.Take` function, and the `string.Select` function.

This is actually quite inconvenient, as I'm trying to port over an old code base relating to string manipulation that heavily utilizes these functions, and I was wondering why/if there's any coherent rationale for the lack of these functions?

Comment: I notice the functions you mention are all LINQ queries. Do you have a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of your script?

Comment: Since it looks like this was not a Unity problem after all (based on the answer below), I'd recommend adding some steps to your troubleshooting process. It's very tempting to jump to "this must be a flaw in the engine!" and it's true that sometimes it is — but not as often as we tend to think. So it's worth pausing to double-check "could this be something *I'm* doing wrong? Is there something different between the working and non-working examples? Did I correctly describe to the compiler/engine what I wanted, or is it giving me the wrong thing, exactly as I asked it to?"

Comment: @DMGregory Fair. Although, I wasn't aware that there were extension methods to the `string` class defined in other packages. That's not a usual feature in any of the other languages I regularly work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity does have these methods:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class StringWhere : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        string s = "Hello World";
        foreach (var letter in s.Where(c => c == 'o')) {
            Debug.Log(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Output in console:

[image: console with two o's]

I tested this with 2021.3.11 (oldest Unity install I have right now), but it probably works the same with any Unity version recent enough to support C# version 3.0 (the one that introduced Linq). I am too lazy right now to research when that happened, but it was many years ago.

The reason why those methods are unavailable in your code is probably because you are missing the `using System.Linq` directive.

Another explanation could be that you are writing Burst-compiled code for the new and experimental ECS architecture. The Linq framework uses managed objects, so it doesn't work in Burst-compiled code. (but if you were using ECS, you should have probably noticed by now that pretty much nothing standard works in Burst-compiled code)

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize System.Linq was required (I assumed, they'd just be included in the class definition for string datatypes). This is really weird (coming from a Java background). Is there a defined way to create extension methods for pre-existing classes in C#?

Comment: @Jax [Yes, there is.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)